# reasons of loss in image quality in subsequent photocopy

Tags: print-design, visual-artifacts

kindly give the reason of defect I have shown in subsequent photocopy made by Kyocera taskalfa 300i, kindly also describe the defect name and reasons. I am attaching the microphotograph image

[image: these are the microphotograph of images which showing feathering or diffusion like pattern in line due to subsequent copying up to 5 generation]

Comment: This is the nature of analog copies v digital. But it's not really a graphic design question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about graphic design

Comment: is this a homework question?!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a graphic design problem and looks like a homework assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Scanning is not a perfect process. A scan will allways lose some fidelity of the original. All measurement is subject to several noise sources, blur and the digitalisation is prone to aliasing errors and so on.

Printing is not a perfect porcess the colors need to be rasterized, the placement has a limited resolution and the nature of the color needs to change. The ink transfer to paper is not perfect, and the paper is not perfect.

So what you see is a feedback loop where your artifacts accumulate over the cycles. We can make a simple thought experiment by using photoshop that simulates the process (not exactly but well enough to get you the idea).

Make a action in photoshop that:

1. adds noise
2. blurs
3. adjusts contrast (manual adjustments and auto levels for example)

Now repeat this action several times and you will notice how the thing degrades over time. This simulates just the scanning process over and over.

You get even more dramatic effects if you include the errors of printing. The printing introduces its own set of errors (you could add posterze and blur on that to the action)

Answer (score 0):

Photocopiers use the same technologies used in the laser printer "Coping over heater drum" the quality of the output is depending of so many factors, one is the drum quality , Ink Workability , scanning resolution and paper grains. from the picture you provide it I think it the paper grains.